# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

When doing:

```
DELETE FROM `salon_connection`.`attribute` WHERE `Id`='4'
```

It gives the following error:

```
ERROR 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`salon_connection`.`datainfo`, CONSTRAINT `DataAttributeId` FOREIGN KEY (`DataAttributeId`) REFERENCES `attribute` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

SQL Statement:

Here are my tables:

```
   delimiter $$

    CREATE TABLE `tabs` (
     `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `TabsName` varchar(450) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$


    delimiter $$

    CREATE TABLE `category` (
    `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `CategoryName` varchar(450) DEFAULT NULL,
    `TabsId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
     KEY `TabsId` (`TabsId`),
     CONSTRAINT `TabsId` FOREIGN KEY (`TabsId`) REFERENCES `tabs` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO   

     ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$



    delimiter $$

     CREATE TABLE `subcategory` (
      `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `SubCategoryName` varchar(450) DEFAULT NULL,
      `TabsCategoryId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `CategoryId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
     KEY `TabsCategoryId` (`TabsCategoryId`),
     KEY `CategoryId` (`CategoryId`),
     CONSTRAINT `CategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryId`) REFERENCES `category` (`Id`) ON   

     DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
     CONSTRAINT `TabsCategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`TabsCategoryId`) REFERENCES `tabs` (`Id`) ON  

     DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$



    CREATE TABLE `attribute` (
     `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `AttributeName` varchar(450) DEFAULT NULL,
     `TabsCategorySubId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `CategorySubId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `SubCategoryId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
     KEY `TabsCategorySubId` (`TabsCategorySubId`),
     KEY `CategorySubId` (`CategorySubId`),
     KEY `SubCategoryId` (`SubCategoryId`),
     CONSTRAINT `CategorySubId` FOREIGN KEY (`CategorySubId`) REFERENCES `category` (`Id`)  

    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `SubCategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`SubCategoryId`) REFERENCES `subcategory`  

    (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `TabsCategorySubId` FOREIGN KEY (`TabsCategorySubId`) REFERENCES `tabs`  

    (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Please help

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 2):

This is foreign keys being enforced.

You cannot delete a row from `attributes` that is still being used (i.e. referred to) by a row in `datainfo`.

You have to either remove all those rows first, or point them at another attribute.

If you want them to be automatically deleted when you delete the parent row, you could specify that the constraint should cascade deletes (but that is a potentially dangerous setting).